# How can I set a wildcard for a File Dialog filter?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to set up a File Dialogue that allows all file extensions between *.000 to *.999. Behind the scenes, we're using a QFileDialog, and the getOpenFileNames() function documentation doesn't seem to explain how to do what I want (or if what I want to do is even possible.

I don't want to define a filter with 1000 parts.

I know the Regex I want is "\d\d\d", but I don't know how to define that for the filter.

So is there a way to do what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: The respective glob pattern would be "*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]" but I couldn't find any hint in Qt doc. that this is supported. (You may try this out.) (Glob pattern matching is the "cheap" pattern matching that shell is using instead of reg. expressions.)

Comment: Take a look at setProxyModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QFileDialog` behaves differently depending on how you are using it:

> By default, a platform-native file dialog will be used if the platform
>   has one. In that case, the widgets which would otherwise be used to
>   construct the dialog will not be instantiated, so related accessors
>   such as layout() and itemDelegate() will return null.

It can use the underlying OS native file dialog, and the question of wildcard usage has to be answered for every platform.

Or it can use a Qt widget based interface. In this case the filters are handled by `QFileSystemModel` and looking at Qt code, one can see that the filters are implemented using `QRegExp` and [`QRegExp::Wildcard`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#PatternSyntax-enum).

```
void QFileSystemModel::setNameFilters(const QStringList &filters)
{
...
    for (const auto &filter : filters)
        d->nameFilters << QRegExp(filter, caseSensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard);
...
}
...
bool QFileSystemModelPrivate::passNameFilters(const QFileSystemNode *node) const
{
...
        for (const auto &nameFilter : nameFilters) {
            QRegExp copy = nameFilter;
            if (copy.exactMatch(node->fileName))
                return true;
...
}
```

So if you can ensure you do not use native file dialog, you can use wild card. To do so you can use [`QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum):

```
fileDialog->setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, true);
```

For the wildcard syntax you have a description in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#qregexp-wildcard-matching). But for your case the answer has already been given by @Scheff: `*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't think this is a solution I can use in my project (for other unrelated reasons), but it does seem to be the most reasonable solution to my problem that can hopefully help others if they have a similar challenge.

Comment: @Taeolas you are forced to use native dialogs? Then you can only hope your OS support wildcard.